# CruiseControl.net dynamicValue for sourcecontrol branch

Tags: dynamic, branch, cruisecontrol.net, cvs

maybe i'm just not seeing it, but i'd like a way to "inject" the value for branch (externally somehow) for a set of predefined build projects.

we have builds configured for Project1, Project2 and Project3.  But at any time, the projects may take from a different branch, based on merge schedules.  i'd like to store the Project=>branch mapping in either an external file or database, then dynamically inject it into the config file when we do a ForceBuild.

The following block is used in all 3 project config files, which are referenced at the bottom (end) of the cnet.config file.

```
<cb:define name="cvs-block">
    <sourcecontrol type="cvs">
        <cvsroot>:sspi;username=johnDoe;password=passTheSalt;hostname=127.0.0.1;port=1776:/$(repository)</cvsroot>
        <module>"$(module)"</module>
        <executable>c:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt\cvs.exe</executable>
        <workingDirectory>D:\CruiseBuild\$(workingDir)</workingDirectory>
        <branch>[SOME EXTERNALLY DYNAMIC VALUE]</branch>
        <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
        <timeout units="minutes">20</timeout>
    </sourcecontrol>
</cb:define>


<cb:include href="D:\CruiseBuild\ACME-project1.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" />
<cb:include href="D:\CruiseBuild\ACME-project2.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" />
<cb:include href="D:\CruiseBuild\ACME-project3.xml" xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate a file (`injectpath.config`) with a defined value:

```
<cb:define branchpath="yourpath"/>
```

...and then include it into your config file shown above at the top.

Change your `[SOME DYNAMIC VALUE]` to `$(branchpath)`.